# Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the administrator by another method

Tags: wordpress

I use Contact Form 7 to send a messages.

In my own server theform works perfect. But client gets this error:

> Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the
>   administrator by another method.

Comment: Try here **http://contactform7.com/support/**

Comment: Why aren't any errors printed in `/var/log/maillog` or `/var/log/httpd/error_log`?

Answer (score 1):

in contact form setting in from field , insert a valid mail from your domain
[this](http://www.technoreply.com/fix-failed-to-send-your-message-please-try-later-or-contact-administrator-by-other-way/) blog help you